# How can I mock/patch a decorator in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking

WORKAROUND:

I was unable to patch the decorator and still have access to the wrapped function. but the workaround for me to test the function wrapped in a decorator was the following:

```
def un_some_method(self):
...

some_method = some_var.some_decorator('somestring')(un_some_method)
```

This still decorates my function, but gives me access to the function if I wish to test it, reuse it elsewhere...

This is the problem:

I have a module, which has a class in it, and variables that instantiate a class which expose a decorator.

Then within the class inside my module, I use this variable with the instance of my class and decorate a method in my class... To be clear, lets look at some code:

```
some_var = ClassX()

class SomeClass(object):

    @some_var.some_decorator('somestring')
    def some_method(self):
        ...
```

in my test I want to test the code within `some_method` and I don't care about the decorator... although my attempts to mock the decorator out was useless... below is some things I tried:

```
@patch('path_to_classx.ClassX.some_decorator')
@patch('path_to_someclassmodule.some_var')
@patch('path_to_someclassmodule.ClassX')
```

none of the attempts above prevented the function from being decorated... any idea why?

Comment: This is a really interesting question, but I am just curious: if the decorator is part of the code, why do you want to disable it?

Comment: because the code within the decorator is tested elsewhere, and to keep the concept of testing a unit, having the result of my function populate a decorator for a different outcome seems to break that rule... plus if the decorator breaks, it would break my test that uses the decorator, which is misleading perhaps?

Comment: I understand you don't want your function to be convoluted with a potentially broken decorator. But the function under test has to run properly in the decorated state, doesn't it? If that is true, it makes sense to me to test it with the decorator functioning as designed. Maybe you can design a set of conditions that will isolate a failure to the decorator vs the function under test? The way I see it, if the test fails, it has to be refactored, whatever the cause. I never had to mock a decorator as you are and when I tried a test case to answer your question I couldn't get it to work either...

Answer (score 2):

One option is to patch `some_var` after you have instantiated it, replacing `some_decorator` with an identity function so that the decorated method remains unchanged.

```
import mock
class ClassX(object):
    def some_decorator(self, f):
        def g(*args, **kwargs):
            print("Hello")
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return g

some_var = ClassX()

with mock.patch.object(some_var, 'some_decorator', side_effect=lambda f: f):

    class SomeClass(object):
        @some_var.some_decorator
        def some_method(self):
            print "World"


SomeClass().some_method()
```

Comment: this sounds to do the trick somehow, but now I am getting an error 'object not callable' when decorator is triggered, not sure if I am doing something wrong, keep you posted and thanks!

Comment: Ok, this works apparently, but the problem is that my decorator takes a parameter and it's a string, so the lambda will return the string and not function... any thoughts?

example: @some_var.some_decorator('somestring')

Comment: That's the kind of detail you need to include in the original question.